# How to get the value of an object after executing a function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function in Kotlin:

```
private fun managerConnect(manager: Manager){
            MnagerManager.connect(manager,
                { res ->
                    Log.d("test", "manager result: ${res?.man.toString()}")
               
                    readInfo(manager)
                },
    
                { err ->
                    Log.d("test", "connect error: $err")
               
                }
    
            )
        }
```

When this function is executed, a value is assigned to the Manager object. And I need to use this object with this assigned value in another function of another class. I'm new to Kotlin so I hope for your help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing `Manager` as argument so any change you make on it will reflect on Object which you holding during calling `#managerConnect` . If you need a callback when the manager changed you can pass in a lambda to get callback .

```
fun onConnect(manager:Manager){
    
}

private fun managerConnect(manager:Manager, block:(Manager)->Unit) {
    MnagerManager.connect(manager,
        { res ->
            block.invoke(manager)
        },
        { err ->
            Log.d("test", "connect error: $err")
        }
    )
}
```

calling will be like

```
managerConnect(manager, ::onConnect)
```

you can modify the lambda according to your need because there is also an Error case and you need to handle it too so probably pass in an error code also. `onConnect` will get called when you get success. You can use modified `manager` object further. See [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).